# In PaperJS allow the user to edit a TextItem like regular text input field?

Tags: javascript, canvas, paperjs

I am using PaperJS to make a canvas app that generates balloons with text inside each balloon. However I would like to allow the user to edit the text inside each balloon to whatever they want it to say.

Is it possible to allow a user to edit a PaperJS TextItem just like a HTML text input field?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The short answer is no, unless you implement parallel functionality from scratch. The solution I have used is to let the user draw a rectangle then overlay the rectangle on the canvas with a textbox or textarea at the same location using absolute positioning. It requires an additional level of abstraction but can work quite well.

It's non-trivial, but here's a basic framework that shows a bit about how it works. I may get around to making it available online at some point but it will take a bit so I'm not sure when. I'm also extracting this on-the-fly from a larger system so if you spot any errors let me know.

```
var rect;
var tool = new paper.Tool();

// create a paper rectangle. it's just a visual indicator of where the
// text will go.
tool.onMouseDown = function(e) {
    rect = new paper.Path.Rectangle(
               from: e.downPoint,
               to: e.downPoint,
               strokeColor: 'red',
               );
}

tool.onMouseDrag = function(3) {
    if (rect) {
        rect.remove();
    }
    rect = new paper.path.Rectangle({
            from: e.downPoint,
            to: e.point,
            strokeColor: 'red'
            });
}

tool.onMouseUp = function(e) {
    var bounds = rect.bounds;
    var textarea = $("<textarea class='dynamic-textarea' " + 
                   "style='position:absolute; left:" + bounds.x +
                   "px; top:" + bounds.y + "px; width: " + bounds.width +
                   "px; height: " + bounds.height +
                   "px; resize;' placeholder='Enter text'></textarea>");
    // make the paper rectangle invisible for now. may want to show on
    // mouseover or when selected.
    rect.visible = false;

    // add the text area to the DOM then remember it in the path
    $("#parent-div").append(textarea);
    rect.data.textarea = textarea;

    // you may want to give the textarea focus, assign tab indexes, etc.
};
```

Comment: Thank you. Could I see where you have implemented this? It would help give me some guidance :)